# Passing a variable to a master template in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, controller, laravel-routing

In laravel i have defined a route like this

```
Route::get('/', array(){
    'as' => 'index',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@index'
});
```

The function index() in the HomeController contains

```
public function index(){
    $index = new ExampleModel;
    $data = $index->getExampleList();
    return View::make('public.index');
}
```

Now the problem is i have a master layout called happypath inside layouts folder in my views which yields this public.index content and i need to pass this $data to layouts.happypath. How do i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers) for example:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\ExampleModel;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $exampleModel;

    public function __construct(ExampleModel $exampleModel)
    {
        $this->exampleModel = $exampleModel;
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('layouts.happypath', function ($view) {
            $view->with('publicIndex', $this->exampleModel->getExampleList());
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

So, every time you use/render the `layouts.happypath` the `$publicIndex` variable will be attached within the layout. Also you need to add the `ComposerServiceProvider` class in your `config/app.php` file in the `providers array`. You may access/reference the data using `$publicIndex` variable in your layout. There are other ways like global shared `$information` using `view()->share(...)` method to share a peace of data all over the views but this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying i 'll give this a try.

Comment: I am not able to get it to work :( I added the ComposerServiceProvider in config/app.php in providers array as 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider' and then wrote the above code in a ComposerServiceProvider.php file. I am on laravel 4.2

Comment: The idea is allmost same but you may check the documentation for `4.2` [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers). Also, have you run `composer dump-autoload` from command line ?

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out the `ComposerServiceProvider` `View::composer` thing. So i basically solved it like this in Laravel 4.2. Added this code to the BaseController.php

```
protected $menuList;

public function __construct() {
    $response = API::pool([
        ['GET', API::url('level')],
    ]);

    $index = new Index();
    $index->setCourseList($response[0]->json()['Category']);
    $result = $index->getCourseList();

    View::share('result', $result); //This line shares the $result globally across all the views in laravel 4.2

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a Service Provider. You can either use an existing one or create a new one.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\ExampleModel;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $index = new ExampleModel;
        $data = $index->getExampleList();
        view()->share('public.index', $data);
    }

    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```

Source: [EasyLaravel.com](http://easylaravel.com/pass-data-to-all-views)